# how to make sure strings have the same number of arguments?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

Why am I getting the `Inconsistent number of arguments in formatting string...found both 0 and 1`   when both versions of the string has the same number of arguments?

English strings:

```
<string name="validation_error_min_digits">Minimum digits required is%d</string>
```

Japanese Strings:

```
<string name="validation_error_min_digits">必要な最小桁数は％dです</string>
```

Comment: Do you have any other `strings.xml` in other folder language?

Comment: Nope.  Just English and Japanese.   I worry that I'm missing something glaringly obvious.  But right now I'm wondering if it is a bug in Android Studio.